# Easy Way to share data in Angular directive

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular5, angular2-directives

I have written directive in Angular 5 and it is used more than 50 times in same page. I want to create dummy list which should be accessible to all elements which used this directive. To achieve this I see two options. Let me know if any other easy way

1. Send that list to directive from component. I don't want to go for this because I don't want user to worry about this.
2. Add a service and store there. But my worry is I will be using that list very frequently.Is it fine?

Comment: Your question is little bit confuse to understand. Could you add your codes?

Comment: this is very close to an _opinion gathering_ question. #2 is your solution.Whenever you think about sharing anything in Angular, the first thought should be to use a service. Services are **singletons** so will only be created once - then the singleton is used. So yes, a service is okay.

Comment: Can you describe the business here a little bit more? You may be approaching this from a wrong angle.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thnak you very much

Comment: JihoonKwon  and BunyaminCoskuner - On click of any of these components (which use that directive) I need to save some data in the list. That list should be common across all these components. But that is temporary list and i no need to expose that to user(other developers) who are using this directive

Comment: Then I think Randy's advice is way to go. You should create a service for that.